# Summarise within groups dplyr

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, dataset

I have a dataset like below:

```
BRAND  MEDIUM      W1   W2   W3   W4   W5

   B1   tv          1    0    1    0    2
   B2   tv          0    0    0    0    0
   B1   radio       0    1    2    5    3
   B1   tv          0    0    0    0    0
   B2   radio       0    4    1    1    1
   B1   newspapers  7    4    2    1    0
```

What I am trying to do is to group by BRAND and sum the value along each column to form a unique row made up of the summed values. Furthermore I'd also like to show which MEDIUM were in each subgroup.

The final output should be the following:

```
          W1    W2   W3   W4   W5  tv radio newspaper 

   B1      8    9    5    6    5   1   1       1
   B2      0    4    1    1    1   1   1       0
```

I'm having hard time to find a way to solve this, especially the second part to put which medium was in the group.
Any suggestion  or hints?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea that creates two different data frames and joins them together to get your expected output. The first is an aggregation on `BRAND`, and the second one dummifies the `MEDIUM` i.e.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df %>% 
    group_by(BRAND) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(starts_with('W')), funs(sum))

# A tibble: 2 x 6
#  BRAND    W1    W2    W3    W4    W5
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 B1        8     5     5     6     5
#2 B2        0     4     1     1     1

df2 <- df %>% 
    select(BRAND, MEDIUM) %>% 
    group_by(BRAND) %>% 
    mutate(new = 1) %>% 
    distinct() %>% 
    spread(MEDIUM, new, fill = 0)

# A tibble: 2 x 4
# Groups:   BRAND [2]
#  BRAND newspapers radio    tv
#  <fct>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 B1             1     1     1
#2 B2             0     1     1
```

Join them together to get,

```
left_join(df1, df2)
#Joining, by = "BRAND"
# A tibble: 2 x 9
#  BRAND    W1    W2    W3    W4    W5 newspapers radio    tv
#  <fct> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 B1        8     5     5     6     5          1     1     1
#2 B2        0     4     1     1     1          0     1     1
```

Answer (score 4):

Mybe in late, but you can also try to manage it without any external packages, in two steps:

First aggregate the `W...` by `BRAND` :

```
# aggregate by brand, and not using the MEDIUM column:
one  <-   aggregate(. ~ BRAND, data = dats[,-2], sum)
```

Then the mediums:

```
# frequencies
# EDIT HERE
# two <- as.data.frame.matrix(table(dats$BRAND,dats$MEDIUM))  
# replace with ones
# two[(two)>1] <- 1

# thanks to Ronak Shah
two <- data.frame(BRAND = unique(dats$BRAND), +(table(dats$BRAND, dats$MEDIUM) > 0))
```

Last you can merge the two datasets:

```
merge(one, two)
  BRAND W1 W2 W3 W4 W5 newspapers radio tv
1    B1  8  5  5  6  5          1     1  1
2    B2  0  4  1  1  1          0     1  1
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah very nice, added! Is there a way in your opinion to avoid the `two$BRAND <- rownames(two)` using the `table()` function? I find it so much ugly in two rows.